# クレカ決済APIをwordpress(woocommerce)に導入する方法

Tags: api, wordpress

https://www.convergepay.com/converge-webapp/developer/#/welcome （英語サイト）

EC/wordpressサイトにクレカ決済を導入したいと考えています。
使用するのはリスト内 In-app payments の ElavonPay という決済方法で、Converge APIを使用する予定です。
Elavon（北米のクレカ決済代行会社）にて、PINコードは取得済みです。

私の開発レベルとしては、Code samplesのページ等が助けになるかと思い、wordpressなのでひとまずPHP形式を使用するのだろう・・・といったところです。
https://www.convergepay.com/converge-webapp/developer/#/converge/samples
上記サンプルコードより、アカウントID等を編集した後の作業がどんなものになるのか知りたいです。

- converge.php
- error.php
- response.php
- PHP Batch Import Script

サンプルページにある、これらのファイルのみで導入可能なんでしょうか。
他に必要なデータはありますか？

お時間のある方、詳細な導入方法を教えて頂けたら幸いです。
こちらの提示した情報で何か足りないようでしたら、提供できます。

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

> サンプルページにある、これらのファイルのみで導入可能なんでしょうか。

サンプルコードはAPIの呼び出し方を説明しているだけで、そこに必要な情報を集めたり、APIの呼び出し結果をユーザーに示すページや処理は**あなたが書かないといけません**。

IDやPINをはめ込んでどこかに配置すれば完成、とはなりません。

ちなみに、PHPのサンプルコードでは決済ごとに変化するパラメータ（カード番号や決済金額など）を `$_REQUEST` から機械的に転記するコードになっているようなので、それらのパラメータはコード中に記載がありません。そこはきちんとリファレンスを読まなければいけませんし、そもそもこのロジックをそのまま使うのはセキュリティ的にも問題がありそうな…。

もし WooCommerce を使われているのであれば、下記のプラグインを買った方が早いでしょう。

[Elavon Converge Payment Gateway - WooCommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/elavon-vm-payment-gateway/)

Comment: やはりそうでしたか…。開発者でないと厳しいですね。新規のサブスクリプション購入はクライアントがノーと言ったため、表題の投稿に至りました。